# Find url ending in .rss with python beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find a way to get rss feed urls similar to the one by itunes movie trailers i.e.

```
<a href="http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/home/rss/newtrailers.rss">
```

How do I match urls ending in .rss using beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` module and pass a regex pattern to match the attribute, e.g. to match *rss* at the end of string, you can use `rss$`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<a href="http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/home/rss/newtrailers.rss"></a>
<a href="http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/home/rss/newtrailers"></a>""", "html.parser")

import re
soup.find_all("a", {"href": re.compile("rss$")})
# [<a href="http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/home/rss/newtrailers.rss"></a>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the `a` tags you find in a page and check if their `href` field ends in .rss

```
for link in page.findAll(`a`):
    if link['href'].endswith('.rss'):
        **do something**
```